# Elasticsearch: TransportError(406, u'Content-Type header is missing')

Tags: elasticsearch

I just new learn Elasticsearch and I have a problem about it but I can't find solution for this poblem. This is my problem

```
File "/home/dat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
TransportError: TransportError(406, u'Content-Type header is missing')
```

I don't know why.. Now, I use Elastsearch version 6.4.2 ..

Comment: What is the python version? Have you checked this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/718. Did you tried this `pip install -U elasticsearch`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. My python is 2.7 .. I tried that solution but It's have another issue ---------ERROR:root:Uncaught exception running rule TestEmail: create() takes at least 5 arguments (5 given)

Comment: no the python version, the elastic library in python! Could you check if the output of  pip freeze | grep elasticsearch match your es server version installed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677645/typeerror-search-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-doc-type-for-elastic-se)

Remove: `pip uninstall elasticsearch` and then Install `pip install elasticsearch==5.5.3`