# TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type' for elastic search version 5.6

Tags: python, elasticsearch, doctype

I want to read the documents from a specific index and a specific type from elastic search. I construct the query:

`es.search(index="document_index, doc_type="document_type", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})['hits']['total']`

I receive the error `TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type'`. I went through a couple of links given below to look for a solution but everywhere the main answer is to downgrade the ES version. But our requirement is to keep ES version 5.6.

- https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-in-python-c3598e718380
- https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/02/how-to-query-elasticsearch-with-python/

and a couple of more

Is there an alternative to mention the document type?

Comment: What is the version of the ES python client library that you are using?

Comment: The ES python client version is 5.6

Answer (score 6):

Seems your elasticsearch python client version is higher than `v5.6`. Remove the existing one with a `doc_type` compatible version e.g 5.5.3

**Remove**:  `pip uninstall elasticsearch`
and then **Install** `pip install elasticsearch==5.5.3`

**N.B** I'm suggesting to do that because elasticsearch doesn't support multiple doc types per index any more using `doc_type`

Answer (score 1):

There is no another type. It is giving error due to different version

Yesterday I faced the same problem You need to check the elasticsearch version or You can directly download the version by this command:
sudo pip install elasticsearch==version(e.g 6.3.1)

You can check current elastic version by this command - pip freeze